# Force.com OAuth Endpoint Configurable

Tags: force.com, oauth2, java

I want to make my Force.com OAuth endpoint applicationContext configurable so it can change to http://test.salesforce.com when someone select to login to their sandbox environment. Below is the the Spring Security Configuration to configure the endpoint.

```
 <fss:oauth logout-url="/logout" default-logout-success="/" store-data-in-session="true">
    <fss:oauthInfo endpoint="http://login.salesforce.com"
                   oauth-key="#{systemEnvironment['OAUTH_CLIENT_KEY']}"
                   oauth-secret="#{systemEnvironment['OAUTH_CLIENT_SECRET']}"/>
</fss:oauth>
```

Any suggestions?